# Laravel 5.1 NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1, laravel-routing

I have an error which you can see in [this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q3bTZ.png), and I don't know how to fix it. I am using Laravel 5.1.

Error:

Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found.

NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161

Comment: Umm... your route is `/alert` but you are trying to load `/laravel/alert` in your browser?

Answer (score 1):

Either make your route something like in your Routes.php file from **App\Http** folder
Route::get('/laravel/alert/',function(){

//statement here

});

or change your page url to **localhost/alert**

Hope it will help you.

## happyCoding

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you Apache configuration is already pointed to your public folder in your project folder as `DocumentRoot`, it should able to work by accessing this route:

`localhost/alert`

I noted you use `localhost/laravel/alert` which looks wrong because you set your route to be `/alert` not `laravel/alert`

If you are not sure this is Apache or Laravel issue, run `php artisan serve` on the project folder and access the routes with this address, `localhost:8000/alert`